# gradle artifactory plugin fails to publish with groupID

Tags: gradle, artifactory

In my build.gradle script, publishing works when the groupId is left undefined. I would like to use "org.company.foobar.common" for the groupId.

When I uncomment the groupId lines in the following build.gradle script, I receive an error. Below the script is the execution results when this groupId is defined.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/jcenter/"} 
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/MavenCentral/"}
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/gradlePlugins/"}
  }

 dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
  }
}

  repositories {
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/jcenter/"} 
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/MavenCentral/"}
    maven { url "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/gradlePlugins/"}
  }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

def getArtifactoryUrl() {
    return "http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        def artifactoryMcentralUrl = getArtifactoryUrl() + "MavenCentral/"
        maven {url artifactoryMcentralUrl }
    }
}

  dependencies {

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "/src"
        }
    }
}

//project.group = 'org.company.foobar.common'

task printProps {
    doLast {
        println artifactory_user
        println artifactory_contextUrl
        //println project.group
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            //groupId project.group
            artifactId project.getName()
            version '1.0.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    def artifactoryUrl = getArtifactoryUrl()
    contextUrl = artifactoryUrl
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}" 
            password = "${artifactory_password}" 
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

The output from "gradle artifactoryPublish" when using the groupId (uncommented) is:

```
$ gradle artifactoryPublish
:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://tribe.ust.doj.gov:8085/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/org/company/foobar/common/kambucha/1.0.0/kambucha-1.0.0.jar
:artifactoryPublish FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':artifactoryPublish'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 409 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors:
The repository 'libs-snapshot-local' rejected the resolution of an artifact 'libs-snapshot-local:org/company/foobar/common/kambucha/1.0.0/kambucha-1.0.0.jar' due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy. Status code: 409

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.84 secs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems, you are trying to publish a RELEASE artifact to a SNAPSHOT repository. When using maven repositories in Artifactory, you will need to make sure that you are following both the Maven layout, and the release / snapshot policy. 
In this specific example it seems that your issue is as following:
Artifactory, following maven policy, is recognizing the following path:
'libs-snapshot-local:org/company/foobar/common/kambucha/1.0.0/kambucha-1.0.0.jar' as a release, while the repository is set to handle only snapshots. For this specific path to work, and in case this is really a snapshot artifact, you will need to change the path to be: 
libs-snapshot-local:org/company/foobar/common/kambucha/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/kambucha-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

If this is a release, change your deployment path to use 'libs-release-local' repository

You can read more on the repository configuration [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories)

Comment: I added the extension, '-SNAPSHOT'. to the version and deployment was successful. The link to the repository configuration was also valuable.